# Cordova app how to change the Android ORIGIN header value

Tags: android, cordova, cors, xmlhttprequest, http-headers

In iOS, my app HTTP request headers have `Origin: ionic//myapp`

In Android, my app HTTP request headers are: `Origin: http://localhost`

How can I change the Android Origin value to be like iOS and/or just list my app name? - localhost seems useless.

Comment: Hi friend can set <allow-intent href="http://*/*" /> or origin='*' for all or specific access , help with official documentation  cordova seccion whitelist https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/11.x/guide/appdev/allowlist/index.html

Answer (score 1):

I will answer for Cordova only. Since you didn't mention the version, not sure this will work for you. You can set a scheme and hostname in preferences, such as

```
<preference name="scheme" value="https" />
<preference name="hostname" value="whatever" />
```

Comment: I actually discovered this later after I had posted this.  One thing to note about changing the `hostname` of an existing app...A BIG THING....is that the app gets deployed like a new app.  The app with hostname=http://localhost` was completely over written - all settings were gone.   After the hostname change, it was like I had installed my app for the first time.  Is there any way around this?  I need to make the change, but all my Android app users will be forced to recover their existing accounts....and not certain I can avoid this.